# Is it possible to combine django-allauth with django-graphene?

Tags: python-3.x, django, graphql, django-allauth

I'm trying to learn how to create a Facebook login API using Django-allauth but my limited knowledge tells me that the library requires using the Django template engine to authenticate the user by providing the user with the correct `{{ form }}`.

So I'm not sure how to create an API version of this functionality using Django-graphene to login with Facebook on a React or Flutter app. Any advice or links to useful articles will be much appreciated. Unfortunately, I don't have a code example of what I've tried since I'm not sure how to go about it in the first place.